shows the different part number
My physical microcontroller shows the part number STM32F412RET6, but when I connect it to the STM32 ST-Link Utility through ST-Link V2, it identifies the device as STM32F401xD/E. What is the exact problem?


Welcome! Please update the title of your question to be a bit more descriptive.

Did you purchase this MCU thru a reliable authorized distributor, or did it come from an unknown seller in an online marketplace store?

I strongly believe that either your ST-Link (ST-Link Utility software doesn't normally work with these clones, though) or the MCU you have purchased is counterfeit, probably the latter.

Can you show a picture of your STM32F412RET6 MCU?

Definitely not a genuine chip. Genuine STM chip has STM logo instead of ARM logo.

@hcheung Definitely incorrect as a blanket statement. STM has several genuine STM32 chips with both the ST logo and the ARM logo, and the ARM logo is located in the top left corner as seen on this image. NB: If that chip in particular is supposed to have the ARM logo or not, I cannot say.

Still likely a fake component, though.
